# AttributeError: module 'bert' has no attribute 'Layer'

Tags: python, import, bert-language-model

I imported :

```
from bert.model import BertModelLayer
```

But I got the error :

> class PositionEmbeddingLayer(bert.Layer):
> AttributeError: module 'bert' has no attribute 'Layer'

I also tried with :

```
from bert import BertModelLayer
```

But it also doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to install `pip install bert-for-tf2`

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/bert-for-tf2/

Comment: already installed!

Comment: @Khadija can you please show me outputs from ```pip freeze``` ?

Comment: @Khadija please put information like this in the question rather than comments